# Does nsExec::ExecToStack is waiting the process to finish?(NSIS)

Tags: windows, dll, nsis, vcredist

I am trying to install VC_redist.x64_v14.27.29016.0.exe using NSIS installer in silent mode with no interaction.
This is the code:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'VC_redist.x64_v14.27.29016.0.exe /install /quiet /norestart'
    pop $0
    pop $1
```

I am using ExecToStack in order to get the exit code.

My question is:
Can I be sure that nsExec::ExecToStack waits till the process exits and then returns the exit code? Is there a difference between **ExecWait** and **nsExec::ExecToStack**??

I want to know if the vcredist executable is installed successfully before proceed with the rest of my installation.

[image]

Comment: You really should use a full path when you execute something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the nsExec plug-in will wait for the child process. It will however not wait for grandchildren that outlives its parent process.

nsExec is designed for console applications, you should probably just use `ExecWait`.

```
ExecWait '"$temp\redist.exe" /something /whatever' $0
DetailPrint "Exit code is $0"
```