# nsExec::ExecToStack fails when running NSIS script tring to run DOS command

Tags: nsis

Please note that I am attempting to create a data file as part of my installation script.  Here is what I am using:

```
  # Create config.dat based on user`s previous selection
  nsExec::ExecToStack '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" @echo ServerPort = 2003 > $INSTDIR\config.dat'
  Pop $0 # return value/error/timeout
  Pop $1 # printed text, up to ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
  DetailPrint '$SYSDIR\cmd.exe "@echo ServerPort = 2003 > $INSTDIR\config.dat" printed: $1'
  DetailPrint ""
  DetailPrint "       Return value: $0"
  DetailPrint ""
```

When I run the script, the above returns a 0, so I think it should have worked but when I check the installation directory I see that no config.dat file has been created.

Also, I have tried this command,

```
nsExec::ExecToStack '@echo ServerPort = 2003 > $INSTDIR\config.dat'
```

But when I use it the display prints:

```
Return value: error
```

Here are websites I have looked at but it is still not clear to me how to get nsExec working.

- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NsExec_plug-in
- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html
- [Does nsExec::ExecToStack is waiting the process to finish?(NSIS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982052/does-nsexecexectostack-is-waiting-the-process-to-finishnsis)
- [Exec vs ExecWait vs ExecShell vs nsExec::Exec vs nsExec::ExecToLog vs nsExec::ExecToStack vs ExecDos vs ExeCmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708779/exec-vs-execwait-vs-execshell-vs-nsexecexec-vs-nsexecexectolog-vs-nsexecex)
- [Execute Command-Line Command from NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510710/execute-command-line-command-from-nsis)

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that I have found the issue.  I thought `nsExec` mainly worked with the command line, but you have to start with cmd:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack  'cmd /c "@echo ServerPort = 2003 > config.dat"'
```

For details please see:

[Execute Command-Line Command from NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510710/execute-command-line-command-from-nsis)